# Creating a copy of the Virtual machine using vagrant

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I have a project that is deployed on a CentOS6 using vagrant. I am trying to create a different machine with a different name and IP address using vagrant. Despite me changing the name of the box and IP on the Vagrantfile, it says the machine is already up and running.

I also changed the name of the VM1 and did the vagrant up, still it renames my VM1 to its old name and do not create a second VM.

How can I try to create a so called copy of the VM using vagrant?

Comment: its not clear what you've done - its sounds you copy the `.vagrant` folder of the project which contains the id of the VM so you would have 2 vagrant project pointing to the same VM; but again without knowing what you did, its only guessing so far

Comment: First I did a vagrant package and tried to use the base box to create the VM again. But i could not do that because there was error inthe network configuration. Then i copied the whole project to a different path and did hte vagrant up. But from your comment i think i should have deleted the .vagrant folder in the copied path

Comment: yes if you copy the `.vagrant` folder the 2 projects points to the same VM. If you do not copy, it will create a brand new one from scratch

Comment: Yes. That did the trick.. But is there any other way to make copies of the VM without making redundant copies of the project

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you copy the full vagrant project folder, you also copy a `.vagrant` folder, this folder contains the id (and uuid) of the VM.

So after you did a copy, when you run `vagrant up` from the new folder, it will still operate the same VM than the original folder.

1. If you want to create a new VM from scratch (if you have all your provisioning steps automated)

you just need to remove the `.vagrant` folder from the new project folder, vagrant will create a new VM

2. If you want to operate the same VM as the original one

first, you need to clone your VM, the easiest is to do that from VirtualBox UI, select your original VM and make a clone (integral clone). You can also do a clone from CLI (actually vagrant runs a clonevm command when it creates a new VM from the vagrant box)

Then, you need to check the id of the new VM. You can run from command line

```
$ VBoxManage list vms
```

This will list all vms with their associated Id, you can then edit the id file from the `.vagrant/machines/default(or machine name)/virtualbox` folder. You can also check the index_uuid

This should do the trick. After you made the edit, if you run `vagrant up` again; vagrant will operate the new VM you've just cloned

Comment: I copied the project and deleted .vagrant folder and it worked. I tried clone already. I am having issues with network adapter. There is no ip addr being assigned to the new machine